# An isometric mapping $f:(X,d) \to (X, d)$ is an open mapping

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces, isometry, open-map

In general, the result doesn't hold. For example $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}^2$ with $f(x)=(x,0)$ [Euclidian Norm].

Now my attempt to prove the restricted case goes as follows:

Let $V \subset X$ be open. Then $\forall p \in V$, $\exists$ some $\delta >0$, s.t. $d(x,p)< \delta \implies x\in V$. Now, $d(x,p)=d(f(x), f(p)) <\delta$, and $x,p \in V \implies f(p), f(x) \in f(V)$. Hence, $f(B_d(p,\delta)) \subseteq B_d(f(p),\delta)$

I am unable to prove the other inclusion. We could use the fact "every isometry of a compact metric space into itself is onto", but I am trying to prove it independently.

Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by the "restricted case"?  When $(X, d)$ is compact?

Comment: I should've mentioned that the metric space is compact. By "restricted case", I meant when the domain is identical to thr codomain metric space.

Answer (score 1):

Is $(X, d)$ complete?  If so, I am trying the following.  (And if it is not necessarily completely, the following may indicate a counterexample.)

If $A$ is a closed set in $(X, d)$, let $b$ be a limit point of $f(A)$.  Thus, $A$ contains a sequence $\{a_{n}\}_{n}$ such that $\{f(a_{n})\}_{n}$ converges to $b$.  Our proof will be done when we show that $b \in f(A)$.

Being convergent, the sequence $\{f(a_{n})\}_{n}$ is Cauchy.  Therefore, so is $\{a_{n}\}_{n}$.  Therefore, $\{a_{n}\}_{n}$ converges (because the metric space is complete) to some $a \in X$.  And since $A$ is closed, $a$ must lie in $A$.

Finally, being an isometry, $f$ is continuous, so
$$
b = f(a) \in f(A).
$$

Answer (score 0):

[Isometries are actually homeomorphisms, in particular, open mappings](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Isometry_of_Metric_Spaces_is_Homeomorphism): remember contractions are always continuous, and that the inverse of a isometry is an isometry too

See also: [Prove that a Lipschitz mapping is continuous](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2929326/359302)

Comment: The OP does **not** assume $f$ to be surjective. At least, they don't mention that.

Comment: @user539887 yes.

Comment: You can just restrict the codomain to be the image (and then use the canonical inclusion to reason about the induced topology if you'd like)