# Proving the continuity of upper and lower integral.

Tags: calculus, proof-writing, epsilon-delta

In this problem, we will prove that if $f: [a,b] \rightarrow  \mathbb{R}$ is bounded, then the functions $G(x) = \overline{\int_{a}^x}f(t) dt$ and $H(x) = \underline{\int_{a}^x}f(t) dt$ are continuous. The method is divided into two steps. I will provide the solution for a), but I would like feedback on the epsilon-delta proof in b).

a) Assume that $|f(x)| \leq M $ for all $x$ in $[a,b]$. Show that for all $x_{1}$, $x_{2}$ in $[a,b]$,  $|G(x_{1}) - G(x_{2})| \leq M \cdot |x_{1} - x_{2}|$ and the same holds for the $H$ function.

b) Use the definition of continuity to show that $G$ and $H$ are continuous in $[a,b]$

For a) we observe that (using the definition of upper and lower integrals)...

$$\begin{align*}  % Begin an align* environment for multi-line equations
|G(x_{1}) - G(x_{2})| &= \left| \overline{\int_a^{x_1}} f(t) dt - \overline{\int_a^{x_2}}f(t) dt \right| 
&= \left| \overline{\int_{x_1}^{x_2}}f(t) dt \right| \\ 
&\le\overline{\int_{x_1}^{x_2}}|f(t)| dt \\  
&\le\overline{\int_{x_1}^{x_2}}M dt \\  
&= M |x_1 - x_2|.  
\end{align*}  % End the align* $$
Therefore,
$$|G(x_{1}) - G(x_{2})| \le M |x_1 - x_2|. $$

We can use the same argument for $H.$

$$
$$

Proof in b)

If G is contionius then for every $\epsilon > 0 $ we can choose a $\delta > 0$ such that $\|x - a|< \delta$ implies $|G(x) - G(a)| < \epsilon$. Here  $x,a$ are an anolous $x_{1}$ and $x_{2}$ from a), chosen to be in the interval $[a,b]$ , with $x \le b$

It follows from a) that
$$|G(x) - G(a)| <M |x_{1} - x_{2}| = M |x-a| < M\cdot\delta$$
This means that we can choose $\delta = \frac{1}{M} \cdot \epsilon $
And we end up with $$|G(x) - G(a)| < \epsilon$$

Are there any potential flaws with the proofs?

Comment: @AnneBauval; Sup and inf would be upper and lower integrals, respectfully. May be a LaTex mistake... A line should be over the integral symbol for the "sup" one

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prove that a Lipschitz mapping is continuous](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2929315/prove-that-a-lipschitz-mapping-is-continuous)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof of part a) is fine. You could shorten step b) by just saying: "by step a), $G$
and $H$
are $M$-Lipschitz hence (uniformly) continuous".

Part b) is *slightly* problematic in four ways:

1. begining with "*if* blah *then*..." is clumsy if you want to prove blah. Better say "in order to prove blah, let us prove that...".
2. there is a conflict of notations with your new $a$, distinct from the lower bound of $[a,b].$ Better keep the letters $x_1,x_2$ instead of $a,x.$
3. (it is not a flaw but you should mention it), what you are proving is not continuity at $a$
   (or rather at $x_1∈[a,b]$
   as previously said) since your $δ$
   does not depend on it, but uniform continuity on $[a,b],$
   which is a stronger property.
4. (a detail of proof-writing), instead of "$\dots<Mδ$
   This means that we can choose $δ=ϵ/M$
   and we end up with...", better write: "Let us choose $δ=ϵ/M.$
   Then, it follows from a) that whenever $|x_1-x_2|\le\delta,$ we have $|G(x_1)−G(x_2)≤Mδ=ϵ$". (Because you cannot claim $\dots<M\delta$ *before* choosing $\delta.$) (incidentally, it is more careful to write $\le$ than $<,$ in case $M=G=0$).